# Angular directive AfterContent and AfterView lifecycle hooks

Tags: angular

[Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) states that AfterContent and AfterView lifecycle hooks are only for components (and not directives). Nevertheless, I have a directive that uses them apparently without problems.

**What are the limitations/possible issues when using these hooks in a directive?**

Here is an example of a directive that uses AfterContentInit:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log('my directive after content init');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div myDirective></div>
  `,
})
export class App {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, MyDirective ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Code live on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/K0yCjW7z1f8gu3lL28yO)

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, you're right they will also be called for ***directives*** because behind the scenes angular uses only Directive definition. Read also [Here is why you will not find components inside Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-why-you-will-not-find-components-inside-angular-bdaf204d955c)

I see only one limitation: **It's only guaranteed these hooks will be called for component since this behavior may change without further notice**.

Personally, I use `ngAfterContentInit` inside directive because i know what i do.